# how to parse html tag without class and id

Tags: php, html

i have a html file like this:

```
<table class="table stage">
<thead> ... </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

how can i get the content of specific td tag? the tr and td tag dont have any id or class. the only class name is for table tag. i have this code bud it just return the thead content:

```
﻿<?php


$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTMLfile('http://url.com');
$finder = new DomXPath($dochtml);
$classname='table';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
echo $nodes->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;

?>
```

Comment: did you `var_dump($nodes);` yet? I think you're accessing the wrong item

Comment: use foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
 echo $node->nodeValue."</br>";
} instead of echo $nodes->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue; that will show you all items, but I think it does not make a lot of sense, to get values from any td tag without any relation to something

Comment: why it is the wrong item? thead tag is the first child of the table. but i need to access tbody tag and its content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nth-child()` function of JQuery can help you. Please refer https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/